# Reduction of Integral

Tags: integration, logarithms

Trying to study for my exams, and stumpled across a Integration that i could not solve myself. I looked up the teachers solution, and I dont get how he reduced the integral.

The image is of an integral that has been simplified. I want to know the steps to perform this reduction, calculations rules etc.

[image: The image is of an integral that has been simplified. I want to know the steps to perform this reduction, calculations rules etc.]

Comment: $\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}-x\sqrt{4\ln(2x-1)}=\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}(1-x\sqrt{4})$

Comment: You should post the integral on your question instead of linking a picture

Comment: Note that in @Nick's great comment, the term $\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}$ is factored out.  This is essentially what we do when we have $a - ab = a(1-b)$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Factoring the term $\sqrt{\log(2x-1)}$ yields

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log(2x-1)}-x\sqrt{4\log(2x-1)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log(2x-1)}\,(1-2x)}$$

Answer (score 3):

The specific step in the linked image follows from two things.

First, we have that $1=\frac{2}{2}=\frac{2}{-1}\cdot(-\frac{1}{2})$

Second, we have $-x\sqrt{4\ln(2x-1)}=-x\cdot\sqrt{4}\cdot\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}=-2x\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}$

---

The second further implies that $\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}-x\sqrt{4\ln(2x-1)}=\color{blue}{\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}}-2x\color{blue}{\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}}=1\cdot \color{blue}{\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}} - 2x\cdot \color{blue}{\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}}$

$ = (1-2x)\cdot\color{blue}{\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}}$

We have as a result $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}-x\sqrt{4\ln(2x-1)}}=\frac{1}{(1-2x)\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}}$

"Multiplying by one" using the first observation we have:

$\frac{1}{(1-2x)\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}}=\frac{1}{(1-2x)\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{(1-2x)\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}}\cdot \frac{2}{-1}\cdot (-\frac{1}{2})$

$=(-\frac{1}{2})\cdot \frac{2}{-1\cdot(1-2x)\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}}=(-\frac{1}{2})\cdot\frac{2}{(2x-1)\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}}$

We have then finally:

$$\int\limits_1^{\frac{e+1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}-x\sqrt{4\ln(2x-1)}}\right)dx = \int\limits_1^{\frac{e+1}{2}}\left((-\frac{1}{2})\cdot\frac{2}{(2x-1)\sqrt{\ln(2x-1)}}\right)dx$$

as the integrands are equal.  You may then move the $(-\frac{1}{2})$ outside of the integral as integrals are linear operators.

Comment: Thanks! this really helped me out :)